# Find the Top 3 Text Occurrences by Count with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the top 3 used vendors (by count) per city and type of service provided. I can get the most used vendor, but the second and third most are escaping me. A brief example of the data looks as follows:

```
A       B        C
City  Type     Vendor
LA    Clean    Vend1
LA    Clean    Vend2
LA    Clean    Vend4
LA    Paint    Vend3
LA    Paint    Vend3
LA    Clean    Vend4
LA    Clean    Vend1
LA    Clean    Vend1
LA    Clean    Vend2
LA    Clean    Vend1
....
```

I change the type of service at the top of the sheet so my expected output would look something like this:

```
A       B       C       D
Clean

City  Primary  Second  Third
LA    Vend1    Vend2   Vend4
SF
NY
...
```

Here's my formula to return the most used (primary) vendor:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$15,MODE(IF($A4&$A$1=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$15&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$15,
MATCH(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$15,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$15,0))))}
```

How can I get the second and third most used? I'm open to formulas or vba. Thanks!

Comment: Try the `LARGE` function.  Take a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3AF0AF19-1190-42BB-BB8B-01672EC00A64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the following worksheet and data

[image]

Use this formula in the `Helper` column (D2 and pull down)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$B$1:B2,B2,$C$1:C2,C2)=1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B,C:C,C:C),"")
```

And this formula in H3 (add as array formula <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(LARGE(IF($A:$A=$G3,IF($B:$B=$G$1,$D:$D)),H$1),IF($A:$A=$G3,IF($B:$B=$G$1,$D:$D)),0))
```

and copy to right and down.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Is there a way to handle ties as well? For example, in the LA market, if the primary vendor is both Vend1 and Vend3, is there a way to list both in the cell?

Comment: @nam24 no, it will list the `Vend1` as primary and the `Vend3` as secondary if both have the same number.

Comment: @Peh I upvoted it. The ties are acting wonky, but I haven't had a chance to dig into those scenarios yet.

Answer (score 1):

My first goto was a pivot table, but soon realized that wasn't an option. @Peh his solution should be the way to go due to efficiency for sure.

Just wanted to state a way with just one formula:

[image]

Formula in `F4`:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$31,IFERROR(MODE(IF((COUNTIF($E4:E4,$C$1:$C$31)=0)*($A$1:$A$31=$E4)*($B$1:$B$31=$E$1)=1,MATCH($C$1:$C$31,$C$1:$C$31,0))),MAX(IF((COUNTIF($E4:E4,$C$1:$C$31)=0)*($A$1:$A$31=$E4)*($B$1:$B$31=$E$1)=1,MATCH($C$1:$C$31,$C$1:$C$31,0)))))
```

Enter as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down and right

Comment: I used a pivot table to get out the report this month, but it was cumbersome. I haven't had a chance to check yours, but Peh's solution works great. The only thing is handling ties.